# chrome debugger shows incorrect scope for this keyword

Tags: javascript, webpack, google-chrome-devtools, babeljs

I'm using create react app which i ejected. [image]

I've encountered the `method=()=>{}` for retaining scope and know it as `babel-transform-class-properties`. The code works as expected and the debugger even shows the values above the line i've selected (`left = 100...`). However, when i try to inspect `this` it shows `Window`. If it were really `Window`, this code would throw an error at the first line.

I see that a source map is loaded. What is impacting this and how can I address it?

Ideally i'd like to be able to inspect the variable in the view above. Alternatively, i'd prefer to see the transpiled code that can correctly be inspected over this.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in devtools.

Comment: hmm, unlikely that it's some specific type, or configuration of the source map? It didn't occur to me to check in another browser.

Comment: Not a duplicate of that question but i cant find the actual duplicate. Something to do with intricacies of the V8 engine, it's by design.